# How to display the output of the joins as well as the output of the IF condition?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter.  Below code, I am using in the model.

My issue is, I have to display the output of the join as well as I am using one more condition inside If condition that output I also need.

What I am doing is, I am fetching the records from the multiple tables and passing `membershipForTheYear` column name in the IF condtion.

```
membershipForTheYear output is the year range like 2018-2019.
```

I am breaking it using explode and changing from 2018-2019 to 2019-2020 to get the output from the table. Now I have to display the output of the this and joins on view.

Why I am doing this because I have to display the next year fees with above joins output.

Should I return two results or I have to use some array?

Would you help me out in this?

```
public function upcomingData(){
    $get_s_member = array('members.is_Approved'=>1,'members.is_status'=>1);
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('members'); 
            $this->db->join('membership_details', 'members.member_id = membership_details.member_id','LEFT');
            $this->db->where($get_s_member);
            $this->db->group_by('membership_details.member_id'); 
            $this->db->order_by('membership_details.membership_added_date','DESC');

            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result   = $query->result();

         if($result)
        {
          foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
          $membershipForTheYear=explode('-',$value->membershipForTheYear);
                             $addNextyear=$membershipForTheYear[1] + 1;
                             $activeBTN=$membershipForTheYear[1].'-'.$addNextyear;

                      $where = array('Duration'=>$activeBTN,'is_FeesActive'=>1);
                      $result = $this->db->where($where)
                                             ->from('bMembershipFees')
                                             ->get()
                                             ->row();
                              // print_r($result);
          }
             return $result;  
        }
        else 
        {
           return 0;  
        }


      }
```

Comment: Try This,Declare $response = array();$response[0] = $result;$response[1] = 'other value'; and retrurn $response; and in else return array('0'=>array(),'1'=>'default value') ;

Comment: @M.Hemant, Where I have to add this code inside if condition? Can you add some more code

Comment: at return $result; place

Comment: @M.Hemant, What do you mean by other value?  Can you explain me more?

Comment: Except for the $result which value do you want to return?

Comment: I have to display the results if no records then display the 0. Can you explain or can you add the answer to understand your code with my code?... or should I add update my code in the question?

Comment: Can you show us sql tables

Answer (score 0):

```
public function upcomingData() {
    $respose_array = array();
    $get_s_member = array('members.is_Approved' => 1, 'members.is_status' => 1);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('members');
    $this->db->join('membership_details', 'members.member_id = membership_details.member_id', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->where($get_s_member);
    $this->db->group_by('membership_details.member_id');
    $this->db->order_by('membership_details.membership_added_date', 'DESC');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    if ($result) {
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            $membershipForTheYear = explode('-', $value->membershipForTheYear);
            $addNextyear = $membershipForTheYear[1] + 1;
            $activeBTN = $membershipForTheYear[1] . '-' . $addNextyear;

            $where = array('Duration' => $activeBTN, 'is_FeesActive' => 1);
            $result1 = $this->db->where($where)
                    ->from('bMembershipFees')
                    ->get()
                    ->row();
            // print_r($result);
        }
        $respose_array[0] = $result;
        $respose_array[1] = $result1;
        return $respose_array;
    } else {
        return $respose_array = array(0=>'0',1=>'0');
    }
}
```

Comment: Give me some time to check this

Comment: How do I display in the controller?

Comment: First, Do you get your appropriate output?

Comment: Wait a min, I am sharing the output

Comment: I just print_r($response_array); before the return and I got output.  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                  (
                    //all the columns which I need in joins 
                  )
           [1] => stdClass Object
                  (
                    //all the columns which I need in joins 

                  )
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
          //output form the inside if condition query

        )
)

Comment: Please check this output in text editor.. you will understand it.. and I am getting the correct output.How to I display in coontroller and view?

Comment: with the help of controller you need to send this array to view and in view, you can use foreach loop according to your need

Comment: So I have to use two for each on view page or one? and how can I display the records? Now I am getting the error <p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188920/discussion-between-m-hemant-and-user9437856).